# JavaScript thumbnail image gallery not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A visitor can click upon a thumbnail image displayed below a larger image resulting in that image displaying the larger version of the clicked thumbnail. Safari is loading the image in a new browser tab (window) instead of reflecting the source change on the larger image. The code below works in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Opera but not Safari.

The HTML:

```
<div class="media-column left" data-aos="flip-right">

    <a class="popLink" rel="gallery" href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade.webp">
        <img id="keyImage" src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade.jpg" alt="Girare Roller Shade" /></a>
                        
    <div class="gallery-thumbs">
        <a href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade.jpg">
           <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_01.jpg">
           <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_02.jpg">
           <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_03.jpg">
           <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_04.jpg">
           <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <span class="gallery-in-waiting">
        <a class="popLink" rel="gallery" href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_01.webp"></a>   
        <a class="popLink" rel="gallery" href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_02.webp"></a>
        <a class="popLink" rel="gallery" href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_03.webp"></a>
        <a class="popLink" rel="gallery" href="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_04.webp"></a>
    </span>
    
</div><!-- End Media Column -->
```

The JavaScript:

```
//  Capture Available Product Thumbnails and Attach onClick event for Image Gallery

    //  keyImage src is Replaced and link cancelled.  Without, image will load in new window.
    
    $('.gallery-thumbs a').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
      $('#keyImage').attr("src", this.href);
    });
```

the event.preventDefault() bit replaced a return: false statement.  Neither work.  Perhaps I should mention that I have deployed with jquery v1.8.3

I have included the whole div element in case the rest of the code can be the cause for this problem.  As explanation, a visitor may also click the large image (#keyImage) to cause a FancyBox pop up window to appear displaying even larger images.  Additionally, the site uses an "Animate On Scroll Library" (aos).

I appreciate any suggestions y'all may have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone here suggested using data-src to pass the URL to the JavaScript function. Thanks for the suggestion as it did indeed work. For some reason, that answer was removed.

So, the HTML changes to:

```html
<a href="#" data-src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade.jpg">
  <img src="Roller-Shades/images/Girare-Roller-Shade_t.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

With the script changed to:

```js
$('#keyImage').attr("src", this.dataset.src);
```

The above changes do the trick. Can anyone comment as to why?